# How are sophisticated functions plotted?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

Let's say I have an **easy** functions such as:

$$x_1 x_2 x_3 = 5$$

Then, I can express each variable as a function of others:

$$x_1 = \frac{5}{x_2 x_3}, \qquad x_2 = \frac{5}{x_1 x_3}, \qquad x_3 = \frac{5}{x_2 x_1}$$

Which can be plotted with ease. BUT if I have more **sophisticated** function such as:

$$\left( \left( x_1^{-3} + x_2^{-3} \right)^{\frac{-4}{-3}} + \left( x_2^{0.5} + x_3^{0.5} \right)^{\frac{-4}{0.5}} \right)^{\frac{1}{-4}} = 10$$

I am not able to express one variable as a function of others.

**Therefore**, how, in general, are functions like these even plotted? What mechanisms are being used? What is the general intuition if one wants to plot this?

Comment: Do you know vector calculus? (Also in your example you can untangle things to isolate either $x_1$ or $x_3$.)

Comment: You can think of your last function as defining a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. One common way to visualize such a function is with colors. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring . Another way is to display it with arrows as you would a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field).

Comment: @JairTaylor Where's the fourth variable? I see three variables ($x_2$ appears twice).

Comment: @Ian a little, mostly basics only. Both functions are 3D. There is no 4th variable.

Comment: @Ian Oh, I guess I misread and thought there were variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ in the last equation.

Comment: If you know vector calculus and something about solving nonlinear equations (or are willing to take the latter as a black box), then you can use arclength continuation with tangent perturbations (move in the direction of the tangent, then move perpendicular to that direction to get back on the curve) to draw contours. Similarly you can use gradient perturbations to move between contours. This works *way* better if your relation is actually a function, though.

Comment: Numerical methods can help plot things too.